# GAE object inserted, but count() zero

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Google App Engine, Python 2.7 using ndb

When I run the following test - it throws an error on the last assert ->

```
self.assertEqual(models.Log.query().count(), 1) 
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Log is a basic ndb.Model class. Running these tests Appreciate help.

```
import unittest2

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util

import rm.base.models as models

class TestModels(unittest2.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
        self.testbed.activate()
        # Create a consistency policy that will simulate the High Replication consistency model.
        self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)
        # Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def testModelsLog(self):
        l = models.Log(comment='hello kitty')
        l.put()
        self.assertEqual(l.comment, 'hello kitty')
        self.assertTrue(l.user is None)
        self.assertEqual(models.Log.query().count(), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

What is your question?

The AssertionError is expected.

You are not doing a strongly consistent query,

have you read 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

As it says "To obtain strongly consistent query results, you need to use an ancestor query limiting the results to a single entity group."  which you are not doing.

Comment: It's worth having a re-read of your original post..   You haven't really asked a question, just made a statement then you say "Appreciate help", which means we have to guess what you are really asking about.

Comment: Since this consistency model is to be expected in GAE, what is the expected way to ensure prevention of duplicate keys on insert?
eg: if I have primary key type field, can I somehow combine it with the key? use _pre_put_hook to check this?

Comment: If you let appengine create the key then it is guarunteed to be unique and you can't/won't overwrite another entity.  

On the other hand if you create the key yourself then you could very well overwrite an existing entity.  You will never have two entities with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are setting up PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy with probability 0. This means that 0 is the expected result for the count query.

This doesn't reflect 'normal' behavior, but how the datastore could operate on extreme conditions.

To test normal operations, don't add the PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy policy to your tests, unless that's what you really need to test.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests